# Playwright not opening up link

Tags: python, url, playwright

I'm trying to open a certain link using `playwright`, and I want to scrape the contents of the link. Snippet of code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="msedge")
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com/whatever')
    print(page.title)
    browser.close()
```

but instead it directs the browser to a page called: 'https://example.com/noAppName.html

It directs the page to example.com fine (I'm not really using example.com, just for example), but it can't seem to get to the path of the url. I wondered if this might be because my url is *really long*, and maybe the link has changed for the site, but when I tried it manually, by opening up the page using the **same exact** link that I used for `playwright`, it worked fine. What does noAppName.html mean, and why is it giving me this error? I wondered if the page just didn't have enough time to load, so I made `playwright` wait a few seconds before printing the page title, but it still doesn't work.

UPDATE: Resolved. The problem was not with the code, and had to do with the website, and certain things with logging in (when I opened it manually I had already logged into the website). In general, if you have this problem in the future, I recommend checking out the website, especially if the path of your url seems really long.

Comment: It's difficult to help without the actual site. Every site is different, so there's no telling what's going on.

Comment: The site: https://infinitecampus.org

Comment: Thanks. That works fine for me if I plug that URL into your code, remove msedge, fix the typo and call `.title()`.

Comment: What is the typo? I am running msedge currently, I'll try .title().

Comment: I solved the error with .title(), it's not with the code, it's something else. Thanks so much for your help @ggorlen!

Comment: Typo: `brower = p.chromium.launch(channel="msedge")` should be `browser = `